# Index or String out of bounds exception error

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception, stringindexoutofbounds

My program is supposed to find bad words in a given input, but sometimes I get an out of bounds error. What is the cause of this error?

```
/* Andrew Woan - Alien Message Board Project - Period 1 */
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alien {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dollars = 0;
        int qey = 0;
        int carrots = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a message board post:");
        String post = scan.nextLine();
        String[] parts = post.split("-");
        String username = parts[0]; // Alien's Username 
        String message = parts[1]; // Alien's Message
        System.out.println(username + "-" + message);
        int space = 0;
        int anotherspace = message.substring(space, message.length()).indexOf(" ");
        while (anotherspace != -1) {
            String badword = message.substring(space, space + anotherspace);
            if (badword.equals("qey")) {
                qey++;
            }
            if (badword.equals("^^")) {
                carrots++;
            }
            if (badword.equals("$")) {
                dollars++;
            }
            space = +anotherspace + 1;
            anotherspace = message.substring(space, message.length()).indexOf(" ");
        }
        char lastdollars = message.charAt(message.length() - 1);
        char seconddollars = message.charAt(message.length() - 2);
        char lastqey = message.charAt(message.length() - 1);
        char secondqey = message.charAt(message.length() - 2);
        char thirdqey = message.charAt(message.length() - 3);
        char fourthqey = message.charAt(message.length() - 4);
        char lastcarrots = message.charAt(message.length() - 1);
        char secondcarrots = message.charAt(message.length() - 2);
        char thirdcarrots = message.charAt(message.length() - 3);
        if (((lastcarrots == '^') && (secondcarrots == '^') && (thirdcarrots == ' '))) {
            carrots++;
        }
        if (((lastqey == 'y') && (secondqey == 'e') && (thirdqey == 'q') && (fourthqey == ' '))) {
            qey++;
        }
        if (((lastdollars == '$') && (seconddollars == ' '))) {
            dollars++;
        }
        if (qey > 0 || carrots > 0 || dollars > 0) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Results:");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("BAD");
            System.out.println(username);
            System.out.println("^^: " + carrots);
            System.out.println("qey: " + qey);
            System.out.println("$: " + dollars);
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Results:");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("CLEAN");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on StackOverflow! The community will gladly help you, since we are here to learn, as I am, and to teach, as many experienced users do everyday. In order to that, I strongly suggest you to read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will make your question clear and, hopefully, useful for the community as well. As many people can learn from your doubts, the better. Enjoy your stay, and do not let you motivation go down!

Comment: Couldn't you split the string on spaces and then check each element against the banned list

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain but have you tried changing this line?
space =+ anotherspace +1;

To:
space += anotherspace;

You already increment by 1 with the += and then you want to do it again.  This is from a quick glance.